# How to include whitespace with java scanner class

Tags: java

EDIT-------------
Seems my explanation wasn't all that good so here is a better one of what I need to do.  Here is an example file(ignore the space between lines):

10=android|156.94.34.212|Device 1|5|9

15=IOS|134.58.48.343|Data|3|7

I want to parse each line.  I need to store each part of the line excluding the "=" and the "|" characters and the last 2 numbers are also irrelevant.  So the 5,9,3 and 7 I don't need.  My problem is when I come across Device 1.  I need to save that space and the 1 but can't figure out how.  This would be what I need to show for the first line:

id = 10

device = android

ipAddress = 156.94.34.212

deviceName = device 1

Sample Code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    Scanner id = new Scanner(scan.next()).useDelimiter("=");
    String deviceID = id.next();
    Scanner dataScan = new Scanner(id.next()).useDelimiter("[|]");
    String device = dataScan.next();
    String address = dataScan.next();
    String deviceName = dataScan.next();
    scan.nextLine();
 }
```

Printout leaves off the 1 in "device 1" everything else parses correctly.

Comment: @ochi Nope, both questions aren't related. Vote to close as "unclear" or "why isn't this code working" would be sufficient, since this question can't be answer without OPs code.

Comment: @Tom I was thinking along the lines of @ iciaran's answer -> read the line, split by the known delimiters (but I did not fully articulate that, my bad)

Comment: @ochi OPs questions reads a bit like he actually does that currently, but that is why this question is unclear (at least to me), because the results he gets are strange.

Comment: @Tom to me, OP is using `.next()` to read the input from scanner - which is why `.nextLine()` is a better choice IMHO

Comment: @ochi *"I can parse the whole file and all the lines however"* doesn't sound like he parses lines with `#next()`, because he wouldn't know when a line ends. Or he calls `#next()` five times as a "group", which would be pretty strange/bad.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] with an [edit]. We would like to see how you set the delimiter

Comment: Why do you use `new Scanner(scan.next())`, when you already know, that there is a `nextLine()` method?

Comment: Because I'm reading a piece of each line, I don't need the whole line.  Not sure how I would use nextLine() to parse each element within that line.  I did figure out a solution, might not be ideal but I put an if statement when reading "device 1" that checks if a whitespace was reached, if it was then I use string.concat to append the the rest of the line after the white space and just used string.split to get the words upto the first | character.  It works but like I said might not be the ideal way.

Comment: Yes you need the whole line and _then_ you start parsing its content by using `=` and `|` as delimiter. Have you ever tried to use `new Scanner(scan.nextLine()).useDelimiter("=");` to see how it works?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `scanner.next()`, use `scanner.nextLine()` which returns the whole line, you can then split up the line with `string.split("\\|")` or similar to get a String array of the elements in the line, split with the "|" delimiter.

Comment: Fixed now, missed off a "\", thanks for spotting it.